# Using base plot in R, plot title not appearing

Tags: r, plot, label

I am having the strangest problem all of a sudden. I am running a plot function in base R (Rstudio) and the plot title is not showing up. Here is sample code:

```r
plot(1:10, 1:10, main = "test")
```

[image: Output of above command]

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I have tried (I think) resetting to the default par values. My output of `par()`:

```
$xlog FALSE
$ylog FALSE
$adj 0.5
$ann TRUE
$ask FALSE
$bg "transparent"
$bty "o"
$cex 1
$cex.axis 1
$cex.lab 1
$cex.main 1.2
$cex.sub 1
$cin 0.15 0.20
$col "black"
$col.axis "black"
$col.lab "black"
$col.main "black"
$col.sub "black"
$cra 14.4 19.2
$crt 0
$csi 0.2
$cxy 0.2839338 0.9361156
$din 6.375000 3.916667
$err 0
$family ""
$fg "black"
$fig 0 1 0 1
$fin  6.375000 3.916667
$font 1
$font.axis 1
$font.lab 1
$font.main 2
$font.sub 1
$lab 5 5 7
$las 0
$lend "round"
$lheight 1
$ljoin "round"
$lmitre 10
$lty "solid"
$lwd 1
$mai 1.02 0.82 0.82 0.42
$mar 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
$mex 1
$mfcol 1 1
$mfg 1 1 1 1
$mfrow 1 1
$mgp 3 1 0
$mkh 0.001
$new FALSE
$oma 0 0 0 0
$omd 0 1 0 1
$omi 0 0 0 0
$page TRUE
$pch 1
$pin 5.135000 2.076667
$plt 0.1286275 0.9341176 0.2604255 0.7906383
$ps 12
$pty "m"
$smo 1
$srt 0
$tck  NA
$tcl -0.5
$usr 0.64 10.36  0.64 10.36
$xaxp 2 10  4
$xaxs "r"
$xaxt "s"
$xpd FALSE
$yaxp 2 10  4
$yaxs "r"
$yaxt "s"
$ylbias  0.2
```

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help with this. I apologize if the formatting is off for this question - it is my first on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is the issue with `$bg` as `transparent`? Output of `par()$bg` for me is `white` and the plot looks fine.

Comment: @AdamSmith No, I have `par()$bg` returning `"transparent"` and the plot has the title. RGui, R 4.0.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I just changed that to white, but the problem persists

Comment: The axis labels are also missing, there's something really wrong with something. Can you post the version of R and OS you're using? And check if there's a `.RData` file being loaded on startup?

Comment: HaveYouTriedTurningItOffAndOnAgain? Seriously, have you tried in a fresh R session? At least that should reset settings and restore any overwritten functions.

Comment: > version                   
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree

Comment: Sorry for the above formatting:

version: 3.6.0
OS: Windows 10

yes I tried turning it off and back on, and I tried opening a brand new R project and the problem persists

Comment: Did you alter/delete the "Rdevga" file?

Comment: Of course this should work also on `3.6.0`. Still, are you allowed to update R on the computer you use? Current version is `4.0.2`

Comment: I'm not sure what the "Rdevga" file is. Is there a way I can check if it has been altered or a way to reset it in case it has been altered?

Comment: If this is your personal computer, try reinstalling R.

Comment: Rdevga: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rconsole.html